# count() returns a different amount than a simple select

Tags: soql

```
SELECT count() FROM recordtype
```

This returns 41

```
SELECT count(id) FROM recordtype
```

This returns 41

```
SELECT id FROM recordtype
```

This returns 33 rows

I'm running these statements in SqlXplorer. Why the different results?

Comment: FYI `count()` and `count(id)` are not at all the same thing in SOQL.

Comment: Good callout @AdrianLarson, edited accordingly.

Comment: I tried removing my Profile assignment to a specific RecordType to see if that would remove it from specific query results, but it did not for me. But my Profile does have ModifyAllData. Could you check to see if you see the same behavior? I don't have SqlXplorer, so I just ran these queries in Developer Console and Developer Workbench.

Comment: Could you try the same query in the Developer Console and/or Workbench, just to rule out any anomaly with SqlXplorer?

Comment: My user doesn't appear to have access to the workbench any longer (generally only uses the bulk api), one of our salesforce folks to try it out @DanielBallinger

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I know what is causing it. Or at the very least how to reproduce it.

I initially had 14 RecordType records defined in my dev org. Both the `SELECT count() FROM recordtype` and `SELECT Id FROM recordtype` agreed on this number.

Then I created a new **Inactive** record type on Account. The `SELECT Id FROM recordtype` went to 15 as expected.

However, `SELECT count() FROM recordtype` and `SELECT count(Id) FROM recordtype` both started to return an aggregate expression of 17.

What the extra two records are getting picked up by the `count()` and how they are related to the inactive record is a bit of a mystery.

Making the new record type active didn't reset the counts to the expected value...

Then I tried

```
SELECT Id, DeveloperName FROM recordtype Group by Id, DeveloperName
```

Which returned 17 records with distinct DeveloperName's...

The two additional RecordTypes were:

1. 01270000000UR81AAG  Progress
2. 01270000000UR82AAG  Completion

I can't query for them directly by Id. A bit more investigating and I found that they have the sObjectType of `Metric` ([KeyPrefix 0WJ](http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/09/obscure-salesforce-object-key-prefixes.html#0WJ)).

Progress has the Description:

> Measure achievement based on how much is finished compared to a targeted value. Ideal for tracking hard numbers and percentages. For example: Convert 50 Leads or Achieve 100% Customer Satisfaction.

Completion has the Description:

> Measure achievement based on whether or not the metric is finished. Ideal for tracking milestones, or when you don't have metrics based on hard numbers. For example: Become Salesforce Certified.

---

I suspect you are seeing an anomaly/bug where the count() aggregate function is exposing RecordType records that you otherwise don't have access to. E.g. You can't create or otherwise access `Metric` records.